# C# tool in GitHub

Tags: c#, git, github

I have to code in C# and a project has a readme file on GitHub. I have to make an application. I haven't used GitHub but after googling I was able to install GitHub Window desktop application and I have forked and then cloned the project repository. Now problem I am facing is how to code in C# in GitHub should I code in native way in Visual studio and then just copy paste the code folder on GitHub or GitHub provide some tools to code in C#.

Comment: Is this your interview or ours?

Comment: Its mine i am not asking the code for interview question I am asking how to use github.

Comment: This will help you. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/581907/Integrating-and-Using-Github-in-Visual-Studio-2012.aspx

Comment: GitHub is just a site that offers Git repositories. Instead of randomly googling for GitHub, you need to learn about version control and Git. Part of the question is to see whether you understand about version control (and Git specifically) or you just googled for a quick answer. The phrase "how to code in C# in GitHub" isn't promising - version control has nothing to do with the language. You really need to find a tutorial on Git

Answer (score 2):

Github is really just a source control system.

You should clone your repository to a local folder. Code you project in that folder. Then commit and push your changes to the GitHub repository.

Comment: Thanks. you mean its just a software to share data. But my frnd use it in netbeans cant i use it with visual studio

Comment: @ArjunChaudhary no, it is *not*. Git is a version control system. GitHub offers hosted Git services (and more). Be assured you *will* be asked related questions in the interview. It's very easy to detect when someone doesn't know what version control is

Comment: You can use github with anything - its a source control system that works with files. Some tools such as Visual Studio offer integration with it, but at its core you're just checking in files (mostly text files)